# Doubt in Calculus Limit Problem

Tags: calculus, limits

Determine $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n}$ if $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+x_n}=e,\forall n\in \mathbb{N} $$

I have typed 2 methods giving two different answers

---

#### Method 1

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+x_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e\\\implies
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{x_n}=e\\\implies
e\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{x_n}=e
\\\implies
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{x_n}=1$$

We know:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\left(f\left(x\right)^{g\left(x\right)}\right)=L\Rightarrow\ln L=g\left(x\right)\lim_{x\to a}\ln\left(f\left(x\right)\right)$$
$$\therefore 0=x_n\lim_{n\to\infty}(\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}))$$
Now $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}))=0$ therefore $x_n$ can be anything.

---

#### Method 2

Take log both sides and get
$$\left(x_n+n\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=1$$
Also as $$t=\frac{1}{n};n\to\infty;t\to0$$
Now $$x_n=\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+t\right)}-\frac{1}{t}=\frac{t-\ln\left(1+t\right)}{t^2\left(\frac{\ln\left(1+t\right)}{t}\right)}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t-\ln\left(1+t\right)}{t^2\left(\frac{\ln\left(1+t\right)}{t}\right)}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t-\ln\left(1+t\right)}{t^2}\cdot\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{\frac{\ln\left(1+t\right)}{t}}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot1$$

(Used certain standard limits which you can solve by series or wikipedia for more methods.)

---

Please help.

(By the way I typed the note in [Mathquill](http://mathquill.com/demo.html). Really nice to use)

Comment: For any real $\;c\;$ , it can be $\;x_n=c\;\;\forall n\;$ , and thus $\;\lim x_n\;$ indeed cannot be determined.

Comment: @DonAntonio See Method 2 which gives $x_\infty = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I can't wrap my mind around what you did in method 2, @MeghParikh. Sorry...but it looks fishy.

Comment: @DonAntonio If you dont know the standard limits I used I can provide you proofs for them.

Comment: The end of method 1 doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: At end of Method 1 I am saying that the limit is of form $\lim_{h\to 0}(1\pm h)^{(finite\ quantity)}$ which is always 1

Comment: But the "finite quantity" depends on $n$.

Comment: Well even if the finite quantity depends on $n$ what can you say about $x_n$?

Comment: In the first case, you are only using that $\lim(1+1/n)^{n+x_n}=e$, so you can't determine the limit from that information. You have more information than that. For example, if $x_n=\sqrt{n}$, then $\lim(1+1/n)^{n+x_n}=e$. If you forget some of the information of your problems, then you won't always be able to solve your problem....

Comment: Oh, the "standard limits" are very well known to me, @MeghParikh...:) I meant, for example, where do you get the equality for $\;x_n\;$ after "Now" from?

Comment: The point is, you are given a very specific sequence - as you know, the $x_n$ are actually determined. In the first approach, you are only using a property of this sequence, which does not fully determine the sequence. There are plenty of other sequences that have this property, so what that means is that the property is not enough to conclude the limit you are looking for.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have replaced $1/n$ by $t$ and obtained $x_n$ in form of $t$

Comment: Still @MeghParikh, I don't see it. In fact, I don't even see the very first equality in method 2: that should be with a limit, which has disappeared...

Comment: In fact, the very first equality, now that I pay due attention, seems weird: shouldn't that have a limit when $\;n\to\infty\;$ on the LHS??

Comment: @DonAntonio the very first equality has nothing to do with the limit it is just obtained when we take log on both sides in the definition of the sequence(which we can take anytime).

Comment: @MeghParikh , I can't even understand, as said before, how the very first equality in your post can be possibly true if you don't write a $\;\lim_{x\to\infty}\;$ on the RHS...

Comment: @DonAntonio: $x_n$ is defined uniquely so you cannot set it to arbitrary constants.

Comment: @user21820, I've no idea what that means. I remarked that **if** $\;x_n\;$ is *any* constant that equality **in the limit** is true, so the sequence's limit cannot, indeed, be determined.

Comment: You are still just saying that if we only know $\lim_{n\to\infty}(!+1/n)^{n+x_n}=e$, we can't determine $\lim x_n$ for this information. Which is true. That doesn't meant tha limit doesn't exist. There is some really sloppy notation - e.g., $(\to 1) ^ {finite} = 1$ is not math notation, so it is hard to tell what you mean here...

Comment: @DonAntonio Take the second equation of the post and just take log on both sides. What you obtain doesnot have to have a limit.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, the problem imo is that the OP didn't even write "lim"...he just wrote that as equality!

Comment: @MeghParikh, are you saying that your very first equality is so **without passing to the limit** ??

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes,  it is the definition of sequence

Comment: @DonAntonio: Well what Megh wrote is a perfectly legitimate way of defining the sequence, except that of course one has to see that the sequence is indeed well-defined by the identity.

Comment: This is just wrong: $\therefore 0=x_n\lim_{n\to\infty}(\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}))$ Note, you can't talk $x_n$ outside the limit.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I learnt it as a standard law of limit. I am rechecking my notes.

Comment: @Megh Still, something doesn't really make sense in my mind: you're telling me that 

$$\left(1+\frac11\right)^{1+x_1}=e\;,\;\;\left(1+\frac12\right)^{2+x_2}=e\;,\;\;\left(1+\frac13\right)^{3+x_3}=e\;,\;\;etc.??$$

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes that is how he wants to define $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$.

Comment: Well @MeghParikh, then I think your method two is definitely correct. Your first one's end is beyond my comprehension, but the second line there is true **only** if both limits on the LHS exist...

Comment: @DonAntonio: See my answer; I wouldn't immediately say that his second method is correct either.

Comment: I think it is though the OP didn't actually explained it all, @user21820 : if the limits exists when the variable is continuous then it exists *no matter* how we choose to take the limits. The other way around woould be wrong, though. By this, expanding the variable definition from integers to reals just made things harder but if proven it works then we're fine.

Comment: @DonAntonio: That's exactly what my answer says. My point is that we shouldn't assume that the asker knows all this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still solving two different problems. In the first case, you are saying:

> If I know that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+x_n} = e$$ can I determine $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$?

Your conclusion is correct, you cannot determine $\lim x_n$ based in this information. For example, if $\forall n x_n=0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+x_n} = e$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 0$, while if $\forall n x_n=1$, it still satisfies the condition.

But the second approach says:

> If I know that $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+x_n} = e$$ can I determine $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$?

This is a lot more information. This entirely specifies the values $x_n$, while the previous condition only gives you some really loose information about the sequence. So it is no surprise that you can conclude more about $x_n$ if you have the entire sequence rather than just a property that can match lots of different sequences.

Comment: Thats precisely what my method 2 is. I am asking what is wrong with method 1?

Comment: Ah yes, jumped the gun.

Comment: Edited answer to answer the actual question asked.

Comment: Method 1 is nonsense because of two reasons: 1) the last step is vague and makes no sense (the part about "finite") and 2) the conclusion is invalid.  It's like saying you are trying to solve $x^2=1$ and notice that if $x^2=1$ then $x=x$ and then you conclude that since $x=x$ for every $x$ that $x$ can be anything.  Sure, $x=x$ for every $x$, but if $x=x$ it doesn't mean $x^2=1$.  The first equation implies the other, but they are not equivalent.

Comment: Along with Seth's answer I finally understood what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{x_n} =e\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}$$ hence $$x_n =\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} -n$$ and therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n =\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: How did you reach from 2nd to 3rd step? Is it a standard limit I am unaware of?

Comment: @MeghParikh: Asymptotic expansion

Comment: You can use L'Hospital rule.

Comment: @FisiaiLusia: Yes that would suffice here too, but in general asymptotic expansion can do everything and provides bounds on the error terms to any desired order, besides being intuitive.

Comment: Yes this is true but can you pinpoint what is wrong with Method 1 in my question(sorry but I donot know Asymptotic expansion and used L'Hospital rule)

Comment: @MeghParikh: I'll write an answer then. Give me a moment.

Comment: hmmm, I tried $x_n = \sqrt{n}$, and keep getting $L=1$

Answer (score 0):

**Issues**

In your first method, you wrote $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{x_n}$ without proving its existence, so that line is already incorrect, even though it turns out to be still true. In a later line you wrote an expression where $x$ occurred outside a limit that binds $x$. That is just nonsense because you cannot talk about the value of a variable outside its scope.

In your second method, you got the correct answer, but the method is still not quite right. You did not prove that you can expand the domain on which you take limits to a punctured neighbourhood of $0$ (small non-zero reals). Originally the limit was for integer $n$, which would correspond to reciprocal values of $t$, which certainly do not cover all small non-zero reals. So if you obtain a limit of your transformed expression, like here, the answer would be correct because you did cover all reciprocals, but if you do not obtain a limit, it does not mean that the original sequence also does not have a limit.

**Asymptotic expansion**

As $n \to \infty$:

$x_n = \dfrac{\ln(e)}{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})} - n \in \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+Θ(\frac{1}{n^3})}-n$ because $\frac{1}{n} \in o(1)$

$ = \dfrac{n}{1-(\frac{1}{2n}+Θ(\frac{1}{n^2}))} ⊆ n\bigg(1+(\frac{1}{2n}+Θ(\frac{1}{n^2}))+Θ\left((\frac{1}{2n}+Θ(\frac{1}{n^2}))^2\right)\bigg)-n$ because:

$\frac{1}{2n}+Θ(\frac{1}{n^2}) ⊆ o(1)$

$ ⊆ n(1+\frac{1}{2n}+Θ(\frac{1}{n^2}))-n = \frac{1}{2}+Θ(\frac{1}{n})$

I encourage you to learn asymptotic expansion because it works on many limits with no ingenuity or tricks necessary.

Comment: That first line in his answer is a pretty elementary conclusion. If $\lim a_nb_n=ab$ and $\lim a_n=a\neq 0$ then $\lim b_n=b$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I know, but the way he wrote it suggests that he didn't know the exact conditions, and it is very easy for people to make mistakes if they don't always check that the expression they write down actually exists.